# Are properties of Expression<TDelegate> subclasses intrinsic in C#?

Tags: c#, expression

I'm wondering if properties of the `Expression` class and its subclasses (`UnaryExpression`, `MemberExpression`, etc.) are collapsed to inline constant objects during compilation?

For example in ASP.Net MVC it's common practice to strong-type property names of viewmodels, such as `Html.LabelFor(vm => vm.FirstName))`, and `Html.LabelFor` expects an Expression, for which it then inspects `Body.Member.Name`, etc. Are those properties evaluated at runtime (with the runtime compilation cost, etc.) or are they optimized during compilation (like `[CallerMemberName]` in .Net 4.5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "evaluated"?

It is not compiled. All the necessary information has already been prepared during compile-time. So in that sense, it's not "evaluated" multiple times. There's no runtime *compilation* of the expression, that's not what expression trees are about (unless you explicitly call `Compile`, which turns an expression tree into a method delegate, basically).

However, the expression tree *is* created every time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
  Expression<Func<DataTable, string>> e = t => t.TableName;
}
```

In every step of the loop, the expression is created again and again, even though it's provably constant (all the `Expression`s are immutable, and there's no closure).

This isn't *free*, but it isn't exactly expensive either - this sample code produces about 170 thousand expressions per second (it's a very silly benchmark, but not that bad for a ballpark estimate).

Some of the cost is all those `Expression` instances that have to be created. Some is the reflection involved. Simpler expressions *are* a lot easier to create.

However, you need to consider the cost of whatever is *around* this as well:

- So in the context of an UI? The cost is widely offset by the benefits.
- I/O? It's going to be negligible next to any I/O operation.
- Deep inside a loop over millions of elements that add two numbers together? Don't :)

If you find that it's causing a bottle-neck somewhere (profile, profile, profile), you can usually cache the expression tree - as I said, they are immutable, so this is safe and easy to do. In fact, you can easily make huge expression trees that have parameters to be replaced in runtime - thanks to the immutability of expressions, you only need to create the expressions you actually have to replace - the rest will stay the same.

In case of ASP.NET MVC, you're using methods like this to have easy access to object meta data. The massive benefit you're gaining here is compile-time checks for the properties and fields you're referencing - it makes it a lot easier to keep your application consistent, and at the same time, the code is incredibly easy to read ("It's a label for the FirstName property, duh.") *and* write. It will keep up with you through refactorings.

Comment: You mention reflection, why is any reflection needed when all types are known at compile-time?

Comment: @BorisB. Well, expressions like `Expression.Call` need that type information, there's no way around that. For the `Call` case, this is `MethodInfo` of the method being called for example. The compiler-generated code loads the method handle using the `ldtoken` IL instruction, and passes it to `MethodInfo.GetMethodFromHandle`.

Comment: I just found that C# 6 `nameof` operator is the intrinsic alternative to Expressions (in this use-case) with no runtime cost. Yay!

Comment: @BorisB. Yeah, that's definitely my favourite feature in C# 6. Along with `using` static and `await` in `finally` / `catch`. It *is* much more limited than those expressions, though, so I think it will mostly be used for debug information and, well, reflection :D

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the decompiled code using any decompiler or linqpad.  It will create a series of `Expression.XXX` calls to build up the expression at runtime.

For example, the following C# code:

```
Expression<Func<string>> foo = () => "";
```

Is compiled into:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldstr       ""
IL_0006:  ldtoken     System.String
IL_000B:  call        System.Type.GetTypeFromHandle
IL_0010:  call        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant
IL_0015:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0016:  newarr      System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression
IL_001B:  call        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda
IL_0020:  stloc.0     // foo
IL_0021:  ret
```

Answer (score 1):

They are recreated... Even in the most simple cases the `Expression`s are always recreated:

```
static Expression<Func<int, int>> otherFunc;

public static void MyMethod(Expression<Func<int, int>> func)
{
    if (otherFunc == null)
    {
        otherFunc = func;
        Console.WriteLine("First time");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Same Expression<Func<int>>: {0}", object.ReferenceEquals(func, otherFunc));
        Console.WriteLine("Same Parameter: {0}", object.ReferenceEquals(func.Parameters[0], otherFunc.Parameters[0]));
    }
}
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    MyMethod(x => 5);
}
```

Result:

```
First time
Same Expression<Func<int>>: False
Same Parameter: False
```

Here we are inside a method, we are calling `MyMethod` inside a `for`, and still the `Expression` is every time different.